# Find a symbolic link or a record in "~/.bashrc" for a file

Tags: command-line

I have some command I can run directly from the terminal:

```
my_command
```

and it runs well. However, I want to disable it to run this way. I know where it's located:

```
which my_command
```

and it gives me the location of the file of `my_command`. However, how do I figure out where is a symbolic link pointing to it and letting it run vai terminal without specifying the full path? Or a record in a file like `~/.bashrc`. where else do I look for it?

I looked for a link or a record for `my_command` in `/usr/bin` and `~/.bashrc`  but didn't find anything. But it might also mean that I just couldn't find it.

Comment: which or whereis??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be looking at the wrong way. The bash shell doesn't only look at `/usr/bin` but a entire set of directories:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/braiam/.rvm/bin
```

Your command either should be on one of the directories, or have a function/alias that calls it. For those cases you might prefer `type`:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ type jobs
jobs is a shell builtin
$ type apt-get
apt-get is /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Comment: I found the full path of `my_command` in `echo $PATH`. It's like `some_custome_path/my_command`. How do I remove it from there?

Comment: @Grienders you better edit your question and include those details. Also, don't remove binaries of the PATH nor parts of the PATH, you don't know what might happen. Edit your question and include what `my_command` is, and where it's found.

Answer (score 1):

There are more directories than just `/usr/bin` getting searched for commands to run. The full list is saved in the `$PATH` variable. To see its contents, run `echo $PATH`.

Your script (or a symlink to it) should be in one of those directories.

**UPDATE**: Unfortunately, the `$PATH` variable can be set in any file sourced by the shell. Good places to start looking would be `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. Also, some people recommend setting `$PATH` in `/etc/X11/xsession.d/90environment`, so checking there might help, too.

Comment: how do I edit $PATH once it found it there?